# System of linear simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Take some matrix $A$ such that

$$
A 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & \dots & \alpha_{1n} \\
\alpha_{21} & \alpha_{22} & \dots & \alpha_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\alpha_{n1} & \alpha_{n2} & \dots & \alpha_{nn}
\end{bmatrix},
$$

where each $\alpha_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$, and assume $\det(A)$ is nonzero. Also take column vectors $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)^T, \mathbf{b}= (\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n)^T$, where $\beta_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the $x_i$'s are unknown. Consider the matrix equation

$$
A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}
$$

which is equivalent to the system of linear equations

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_{ij} x_j = \beta_i, 
$$

for $1 \leq i \leq n$. I understand that the equation can be solved via Gaussian reduction of $A$, however, I was wondering if there was an explicit way to calculate each $x_i$ in terms of the $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ by repeated substitution?

Comment: Yes, you can substitute, but it will be considerably more work. The most efficient known exact method of solving is still Gaussian elimination with back substitution.

Comment: What you're wanting to do looks like it will boil down to [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Comment: @IvoTerek That's what I was looking for - +1!

Comment: Ok, then I'll convert the comment to an answer and you can accept it (so the question does not stay in the unanswered list) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure you're looking for is [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Comment: thanks a lot mate!